# Find orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthonormal

I'm trying to solve the following exercise in my book:

> Find an orthonormal basis $\alpha$ for the vector space
>   $\left(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2},+\right)$ (with default
>   inner product, $ \langle A,B \rangle = Tr(A \cdot B^T $)) such that the matrix representation $L_\alpha^\alpha$
>   of the linear transformation $$L : \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2} \rightarrow
>  \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2} : \begin{pmatrix} x & y \\ z & t\end{pmatrix}
>  \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} x+y+t & x+y+z \\ y+z+t & x+z+t \end{pmatrix}$$ with respect to the basis $\alpha$ is a diagonal matrix.

I started out by transforming the default bases, as such:
$$L(e_1) = e_1 + e_2 + e_4$$
$$L(e_2) = e_1 + e_2 + e_3$$
$$L(e_3) = e_2 + e_3 + e_4$$
$$L(e_4) = e_1 + e_3 + e_4$$

With:
$$e_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}, e_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}, e_3 = \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}, e_4 = \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Can you please elaborate how to procede with such a problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the _default inner product_ on $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$?

Comment: @JendrikStelzner $ \langle A,B \rangle = A^T \cdot B $ Maybe this is not 'default' but my book names it this way.

Comment: But $A^T B$ is again a matrix, not a scalar. So I wouldn’t really call this an inner product. In particular, was does orthogonality mean in this context?

Comment: I'm very sorry, this of course is not the inner product for $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ matrices, I meant this $ \langle A,B \rangle = Tr(A \cdot B^T) $

Comment: And, orthogonality (more precise, orthonormality) means that for each $v$ in my basis $\langle v_i,v_j \rangle = 0$ (for each $i \neq j$) and $\left\lVert v_i \right\rVert = 1$ (for every $i$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In vector notation your transformation is:

$$
L
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z\\t
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
x+y+t\\x+y+z\\y+z+t\\x+z+t
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so, by a simple inspection, you can see that it is represented by the matrix
$$
L=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0&1\\1&1&1&0\\0&1&1&1\\1&0&1&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This is a symmetric real matrix so we know that can be diagonalized as:
$$
L=SDS^{-1}
$$
where $S$ is an orthogonal matrix with as columns the eigenvectors of $L$ and $D$ is the diagonal matrix with the corresponding eigenvalues on the diagonal.

So, find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $L$ , note that these are orthogonal, normalize them and you have the searched basis, and $D$ is the diagonal matrix that represents the given transformation in this basis.

Answer (score 4):

I haven’t done this in quite some time, so this solution is probably unnecessary complicated:

We identify $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ with $\mathbb{R}^4$ via
$$
 \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2} \to \mathbb{R}^4, \,
 \begin{pmatrix}
  x & y \\
  z & t
 \end{pmatrix}
 \mapsto
 (x,y,z,t)^T.
$$
(So the “default basis” you used corresponds to the standard basis $(e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4)$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$.) If we understand $L$ as a linear map $\hat{L} \colon \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ then $\hat{L}$ is (with respect to the standard basis on both sides) given by the matrix
$$
 A = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Also notice that the inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ corresponds to the standard scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^4$ because
$$
 \left\langle
  \begin{pmatrix}
   a_{11} & a_{12} \\
   a_{21} & a_{22}
  \end{pmatrix},
 \begin{pmatrix}
   b_{11} & b_{12} \\
   b_{21} & b_{22}
  \end{pmatrix}
 \right\rangle
 = a_{11} b_{11} + a_{12} b_{12} + a_{21} b_{21} + a_{22} b_{22}.
$$
(This also justifies called is the *default inner product*.) So to find an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ with respect to which $L$ is diagonal is the same as finding an orthogonal basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ with respect to which $\hat{L}$ is represented a diagonal matrix.

---

There are now different ways to solve this problem. We will first calculate the eigenspaces of $\hat{L}$; because $A$ is symmetric we know that $\hat{L}$ is diagonalizable. Then we will use the following fact:

> ***Proposition***: Let $S \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be symmetric and $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ eigenvalues of $S$ to eigenvalues $\lambda \neq \mu$. Then $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal.
>
> *Proof*: Notice that
>   \begin{align*}
>  \lambda \langle x,y \rangle
> &= \langle \lambda x, y \rangle
> = \langle Ax, y \rangle
> = (Ax)^T y
> = x^T A^T y
> = x^T A y \\
> &= \langle x, A y \rangle
> = \langle x, \mu y \rangle
> = \mu \langle x, y \rangle.
> \end{align*}
>   Because $\lambda \neq \mu$ it follows that $\langle x,y \rangle = 0$.

So the eigenspaces of different eigenvalues are orthogonal to each other. Therefore we can compute for each eigenspace an orthonormal basis and them put them together to get one of $\mathbb{R}^4$; then each basis vectors will in particular be an eigenvectors $\hat{L}$.

---

By some lengthy calculation it can be shown that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is given by
$$
 \chi_A(t) = t^4 - 4 t^3 + 2 t^2 + 4t - 3.
$$
It is easy to guess the roots $1$ and $-1$, so we can factor $\chi_A$ and get
$$
 \chi_A(t) = (t-1)^2 (t+1) (t-3).
$$
The eigenspaces can now be calculated as usual, and we find that
$$
 E_1 = \langle (0,-1,0,1)^T, (-1,0,1,0)^T \rangle, \;
 E_{-1} = \langle (-1,1,-1,1)^T \rangle, \;
 E_3 = \langle (1,1,1,1)^T \rangle,
$$
where $E_\lambda$ denotes the eigenspace with respect to the eigenspace $\lambda$.

---

Next we need to find orthonormal basis for each eigenspace. We can always do this by picking some basis and then using Gram–Schmidt. But here we are pretty lucky:

We know the basis $((0,-1,0,1)^T, (-1,0,1,0)^T)$ of $E_1$. Because both basis vectors are already orthogonal to each other we only need to normalize them. So we get $b_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(0,-1,0,1)^T$ and $b_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-1,0,1,0)^T$.

In the case of $E_{-1}$ and $E_3$ we are even luckier, as they are both one-dimensional. So here too we only need to normalize and thus get $b_3 = \frac{1}{2} (-1,1,-1,1)^T$ and $b_4 = \frac{1}{2}(1,1,1,1)^T$.

---

Putting these together we have now found a basis $(b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4)$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$ given by
$$
 b_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix}  0 \\ -1 \\  0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \;
 b_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\  0 \\  1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \;
 b_3 = \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\  1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \;
 b_4 = \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}  1 \\  1 \\  1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},
$$
which is orthonormal and cosists of eigenvectors of $\hat{L}$. The corresponding $2 \times 2$ matrices are
\begin{align*}
 B_1 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix}  0 & -1 \\  0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, &
 B_2 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} -1 &  0 \\  1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \\
 B_3 &= \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} -1 &  1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, &
 B_4 &= \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}  1 &  1 \\  1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for this map. Choose the eigenvectors in such a way that you obtain an orthonormal basis. Then find the matrix representation of your map with respect to this basis.